# How to install package which depends on outdated library?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I have a package, which requires `libicu55`, when I try to install it in Ubuntu Zesty, it gives me this error: `Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable`.

However, I have `libicu57` installed, which is obviously a newer version. Also, `libicu55` is only available for Xenial.

What do I do about that?

Comment: *I have a package* – which one?

Comment: Download it from the source http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb and install it using `sudo dpkg -i libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: If this package is *yours*, @SlavaFominII, then yuo need to update the package to use `libicu57`.  If it is *not* yours, you need to contact the people who created teh package to have them make a Zesty-compatible package.

Comment: Not exactly that, @ThomasWard. Avidemux, e.g, has no packages for Zesty, but I install it when I apply earlier versions of some packages.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've decided to use portable version of the software in the end and therefore can not verify Redbob's solution, however it looks like a valid option. I'm going to rename the question and leave it for someone who would like to document the possible solutions.